Аутентификация JWT Spring security
Не происходит аутентификации. На запрос к "/succed" через Postman выдаться 403 и всё.
вот код конфета
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final UserService userService;

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer ->
                        httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(request ->
                                new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/secured").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(
                        jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService.userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();

    }
}

фильтр токенов
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JWTService jwtService;
    private final UserService userService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String jwt = authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");
        String refreshToken = null;

        final String userEmail;
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUserName(jwt);
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(userEmail) && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userService.userDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                try {
                    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails, null
                    );
                    token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    securityContext.setAuthentication(token);
                    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
                    System.out.println("success");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

